# finding the coordinates of an NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, coordinates, nsimageview

Im not too used to cocoa yet, so please bear with me

I am writing a game for mac in Objective-C on cocoa, and I have one problem:

I have two NSImageViews, and i need to set it up so that if I move one, the other one follows it ON THE Y AXIS ONLY. How do I find out the coordinates of the first image so that i can apply the x value to the second one?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this works with NSImageView, but it works with UIImageView.

```
yourImage.frame.origin.x;
```

I hope that helps